# I can't made web3 subscribe filter work

Tags: web3js, transactions

I'm trying to get a subscription to logs from a "target" address, but I wasn't able to make filters works.
Subscribe method works without filter but I wasn't able to print a result without it, I get the Subscription ID so I'm connected but 0 logs after that.
The transaction used to test is a simple eth transfer on goerli.

```js
import Web3 from 'web3';

let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://node-name.ethereum-goerli.discover.quiknode.pro/myKey/"));
web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
}, function (error, result) {
    if (!error)
        console.log(result);
})
    .on("connected", function (subscriptionId) {
        console.log("SubsID", subscriptionId);
    })
    .on("data", function (log) {
        console.log(log);
    })
    .on("changed", function (log) {
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have to add the "topics" that you want to subscribe to as well, you can find the topic hash from the "logs" tab of any transaction on etherscan like this: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xde4c388f96aec17194a8ffa18393ab7eab956a73163ab2c870ce64efe3deea5a#eventlog.

Here is a code example if you're looking for the transfer topic:

```
web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    // enter array of topics to subscribe to:
    topics: [
      // topic hash for "transfer" 
      '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'
      // topic inputs example for "transfer" event takes "to", "from", and "tokenId"
      ['0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', null, null],
      // this example will give you all transfers from zero address to any address by leaving "to" and "tokenId" as null
    ],
});
```

and here is a link to the docs if you need further clarification:
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.1/web3-eth-subscribe.html#id16

Comment: Thanks! that will solve all my issues ❤

Comment: no problem Mentasuave